# Anonymous functions accessing local variables [ActionScript - Flex 3.5]

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am having a situation with my actionscript/flex front end.

```
 for each (var sym:String in ["A","B","C"]) {

                const handler = function (data:Object):void { Alert.show(sym); }                

                asyncCallback(handler);

   }
```

I am expecting to have 3 Alert windows containing A, B and C. But the actual result is 3 alert windows all showing C !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky. You have to wrap your handler creation inside another function.

try:

```
for each(var sym:String in ["A","B","C"]) {
    function createHandler(val:String):Function {
        var handler = function(data:Object):void { 
            trace(val); 
        }
        return handler;
    }
    var handler:Function = createHandler(sym);
    asyncCallback(handler);
}
```